# AJAX not working with Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

For some reason, I cannot get an AJAX function

```
$('#queueSubmit').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: nodeApiUrl + 'twitter/update_status/',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({'status': $('#queuedTweet').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                error: $.osf.handleJSONError
        });
});
```

to be called when I click the button with id `queueSubmit`.  This is the knockout code that generates the buttons and content.

```
   <div id = "foo">
    <!-- ko foreach: tweets -->

        <input id = "queuedTweet" data-bind="value: tweet"/>
        <a  class="btn btn-primary" id = "queueSubmit" >
            Send
        </a>
        <a id = "removeFromQueue" data-bind = "click: $parent.removeTweet, value:index" class="btn btn-danger">
            Delete
        </a>
       </br>

     <!-- /ko -->
   </div>
```

It does not register that the button is being clicked.  I believe it has something to do with the bindings but not sure how to remedy.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using Knockout for one click event and jQuery for another?  It probably makes more sense to use Knockout for both.  For the jQuery one, is Knockout removing/re-adding the `queueSubmit` element from/to the DOM?  If so, that would cause the the jQuery click event to lose its binding to that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want do do this instead of your current implementation:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.queueSubmit">Send</a>
```

Then in your viewModel do this:

```
self.queueSubmit = function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: nodeApiUrl + 'twitter/update_status/',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({'status': $('#queuedTweet').val() }),
            dataType: 'json',
            error: $.osf.handleJSONError
    });
};
```

Use knockout bindings any time you can. If a native binding doesn't exist, create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: When I try this, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: queueSubmit is not defined

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$parent.queueSubmit` just as you have `$parent.removeTweet`.

Answer (score 2):

IDs are supposed to be unique, but you are creating them within a ko foreach loop. That means you actually have an array of "queueSubmit" IDs. jQuery assumes you will only have one, so it always retrieves the first one in the list.

You can see this in action by using the native JavaScript functions:

```
document.querySelector("#queueSubmit"); // <== returns the first one in the list
document.querySelectorAll("#queueSubmit"); // <== return the array of elements with that id
document.querySelectorAll("#queueSubmit")[n]; // <== returns the element at index 'n'
```

Duplicating IDs is a really bad idea (I've always been surprised that this is even allowed, but it is).

That leads to the question "why are you using an ID"? If you are going to replicate it like this, then either make the IDs unique or replace them with a class. (The class option is much better).

Even better, like @Cameron suggested, use a click binding to a function inside your KO ViewModel instead. This will also have the added benefit of automatically passing the bound data item (the current instance of the foreach loop) to the function.

```
<div id = "foo">
<!-- ko foreach: tweets -->

    <input id = "queuedTweet" data-bind="value: tweet"/>
    <a  class="btn btn-primary" click="$parent.queueSubmit" >
        Send
    </a>
    <a id="removeFromQueue" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTweet, value:index" class="btn btn-danger">
        Delete
    </a>
   </br>

 <!-- /ko -->
```

And then in your ViewModel:

```
self.queueSubmit = function(item) { // <== current tweet is passed in automatically 
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: nodeApiUrl + 'twitter/update_status/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({'status': item.tweet }), // <== use the item, not jQuery
        dataType: 'json',
        error: $.osf.handleJSONError
    });
};
```

You can learn more about [the click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) at the KO website

Answer (score 0):

You can't use IDs in this way. You should register a `click` binding.

Comment: how can I use a click to bind to an ajax function?  I only know how to bind to a knockout function, as in .removeTweet

Comment: right but you call `$.ajax`. you don't need jquery's `click`.